# Messenger bot does not respect the message order

Tags: bots, messenger

I'm having an issue with Messenger dev platform and guessed I could ask you guys for some help.

I would like my bot to send multiple messages in a row, for exemple :

```
sendTextMessage(user, "Hello");
sendTextMessage(user, "Goodbye");
```

But since Node is asynchrone, the order is not always respected and sometimes 'Goodbye' ends up showing before 'Hello'.

What is the best solution to remedy this issue ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in NodeJS by using either **callbacks** or **promises**. If you are not familiar with either of them, you can read [callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) and [promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies).

For further more steps, please check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497119/6874563

I used above and get solved.