# Sending multiple reply messages on single postback in Facebook Messenger Bots

Tags: json, node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I want to send multiple replies for a single user-triggered postback on Messenger. I've been following Messenger's [developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) and couldn't really find how to do this.

My code structure is very similar to the tutorials they've given on the site, I have a '**handlePostback**' function which identifies the received postback and compares it to a set of predefined payloads to find the '**response**' JSON object. This response is given to '**callSendAPI**' which puts this JSON object into the basic format of sending the message back to the Messenger API.

```
function handlePostback(sender_psid,receivedPostback)
{ if(payload== 'defined_payload') {
  response = {
  text: 'Some text'
  };
callSendAPI(sender_psid,response);
}

function callSendAPI(sender_psid,response) {
let body = {
recipient: {
id= sender_psid
},
message: response
};
// Followed by code for POST request to the webhook
}
```

This being the basic structure, now I want to send multiple messages as a reply to **one postback**. I did some digging, and I found that the solution might be to create a message [] array. But how do I do this? Because my 'response' is being generated through that function, and the messages structure should look like this (I think):

```
let body = {
 recipient: {
 id=sender_psid
 },
 messages: [ {
  response1
  },
  {
  response2
  }
 ]
};
```

I hope I could explain my question, please let me know if I can provide more details!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice question. If you are not familiar with Node.js the way to do it is not too obvious and this is not documented well on Facebook's Send API Documentation.

Firstly, your approach of sending multiple messages, using an array, as you may have observed won't work. Facebook has a solution for sending up to 100 API Calls with one request but in my opinion this is not needed in your situation. If you want to find out more about it check out the [Batched Request Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/), you'll find out that the implementation is different than yours.

One solution that will work is to call the `callSendAPI` function multiple times. **But this solution has one major drawback**: You won't be able to control the  actual sequence of the messages sent. For example if you want to send two separate messages, **you cannot guarantee which will be sent first to the user**.

To solve this issue you need to chain your `callSendAPI` functions in a way that guarantees that the next `callSendAPI` call will happen only after the first message is already sent. You can do this in NodeJS by **using either callbacks or promises**. If you are not familiar with either of them, you can read [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) for callbacks and [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies) for promises.

You'll need to modify your `callSendAPI` function and especially the part that sends the POST request to Facebook. I will present a solution to your issue by using **promises** and the module [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function handlePostback(sender_psid,receivedPostback){ 
  if (payload == 'defined_payload') {
    response = {
      text: 'Some text'
    };
    response2 = //... Another response
    response3 = //... Another response
  callSendAPI(sender_psid,response).then(() => {
    return callSendAPI(sender_psid, response2).then(() => {
      return callSendAPI(sender_psid, response3); // You can add as many calls as you want
      });
   });
  }
}

function callSendAPI(sender_psid,response) {
  let body = {
    recipient: {
      id= sender_psid
    },
    message: response
  };
  const qs = 'access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(FB_PAGE_TOKEN); // Here you'll need to add your PAGE TOKEN from Facebook
  return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?' + qs, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, when i implement the above method, i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". The response 2 never shows up and response 1 is sent to the user thrice.

Comment: I can't know exactly what went wrong if I don't see your code. I would be happy to help though :)

Comment: Hi i have added the code below in the answer. Let me know if this will be sufficient for you to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below link useful to sort out the way to implement multiple responses on single post back.

https://codingislove.com/build-facebook-chat-bot-javascript/

Like you said, array should work. Create an array variable with multiple response messages

```
var multipleResponse = {
   messages: [{
      response1
   },
   {
      response2
   }]
};
```

And push the array variable to your function

```
function callSendAPI(sender_psid,response) {

    let body = {
         recipient: {
            id= sender_psid
         },
         message: []
    };
    // Followed by code for POST request to the webhook
}
```

Finally push the array to your function array

```
body.message.push(multipleResponse.messages);
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, [SO answers should not solely rely on external links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Links tend to disappear after a certain time, rendering the answer useless. Please state the main points here on SO and use the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

@Christos Panagiotakopoulos. I am not getting my mainMenuResponse which is chained using then. Rather, i am getting response thrice.
handlePostback function =>

```
// Handles messaging_postbacks events
function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback) {
  let response;

  // Get the payload for the postback
  let payload = received_postback.payload;

  // Set the response based on the postback payload
  if (payload === 'fashionTip') {
    response = { "text": getFashionTip() } // calls a function which gives a fashion-tip

  // Send the message to acknowledge the postback
  callSendAPI(sender_psid, response).then(() => {
    return callSendAPI(sender_psid, mainMenuResponse)
  });
```

callSendAPI function =>

```
// Sends response messages via the Send API
function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
  // construct the message body
  let request_body = {
    "recipient": {
      "id": sender_psid
    },
    "message": response
  }

  // Send the HTTP request to the messenger platform
  request({
    "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    "qs": {"access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
    "method": "POST",
    "json": request_body
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Message sent!");
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send mesage:" + err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: In contrast to my example, where I'm using "node-fetch" to perform the POST request, you are using "request". The difference between the two is that "node-fetch" returns a promise and "request" works with callbacks and returns void. 

You'll need to use a promise-compatible function to perform the request, or promisify the "request" function. Though I would suggest to convert to "node-fetch" or to use the "request-promise-native" package if you want to retain the same api.

Comment: Thank you sir, was able to work with node-fetch. Though couldn't make the request-promise-native work for it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -2):

Don't modify `callSendAPI` function. In your `handlePostback` function call `callSendAPI` multiple times.

```
callsendAPI(sender_psid,response1);
callsendAPI(sender_psid,response2);
```